# Maria db move to other partition

Tags: mariadb

I have a 120GB maria db sever on centos 7.5 with 4 primary partitions.

My free storage is  20G and I want to add more . I can not make another partition because I already have 4 primary partition.
I have to delete one of the existing partitiona and covert it to logical. All my partitions are inside logical volumes.

How can I add more partition ?

PS. I can shrink databases size by some percent if it is necessary.

Comment: Just replace HDD with another, larger one.

Comment: What OS?  (Some let you treat two drives as one.)  What is a "partitiwoon"; it sounds kinky.

Comment: Os is centos 8. I can't just replace HDD, It is a vm I cannot replace physical equipment.